# PCB sound memory for toys

Tags: pcb, embedded, memory, sd

I want to build a toy. The initial build will be a prototype but if the idea 'sells,' I want to build en-masse.

For the prototype, as I do not have (beyond what I learnt at Uni) industry experience, I want to make use of freelancers for designing and programming the board.

The toy basically will play sounds based on which button is pressed. The sounds are recorded sound/music. I am currently working with a freelancer who is designing a PCB for this but we are stuck on how to store the sounds. At the moment, SD card is the recommendation but I know that this is not an option due to cost (if one is producing en-masse.)

Can someone please recommend a possible solution? The freelancer has also mentioned possibility of using a semiconductor memory but says that the programming for this will be difficult. Are there other options?

Comment: You might look at an SPI flash.  This question isn't really specifically answerable or on topic here - you've provided none of the constraints needed to actually chose a solution, and EESE is not a free design service - both identifying the specifics of your need and choosing a solution are things that your retained resource should be able to do.

Comment: You should work out the exact requirements. Required memory size and speed, supply voltage etc.

Comment: At work we play simple melodies programmed in a PIC microcontroller. On other products with music we use pre-recorded sound boards manufactured in China.

Comment: you must define the signal quality and bandwidth or memory size and format (compressed). There are cheap low quality flash versions and more $ MP3 decoders

Comment: PCB = printed circuit board.  PCB board = printed circuit board board.  This message brought to you by the department of redundancies department.

Comment: What experience do you have? You state you do not have "beyond what I learnt at Uni" but don't state what that is whether it be software engineering, electrical engineer, applied physics or fine arts? It is troubling that a freelancer who is designing a PCB for you doesn't know how to play back audio from button presses

Comment: @JRE as you like but a PCB is a PCB, it's not an usable toy.The sampler concept is so old and has so many variations that it should be useful to check what is already available. Checking a smartphone version is a good start for finding how to make something new.

Comment: IMHO you need to carefully remove your freelancer from the circuit and get a new one.  Shop for one that *doesn't* find using memory to be rocket science, and back this up by asking what they've *actually done* in that area of expertise.  In buying freelance time, like anything else, the cheapest option is often the most expensive in the end.

Comment: @TimWescott, thank you for the comment. I sourced the freelancer from a freelance website. To be fair, they are only working on the PCB design and they did say that this should be easy but the programming is the hard part IF a memory chip is used compared to a SD card.

Comment: There needs to be an engineering management stackexchange, except that all the questions would be opinion-based.  For deeply embedded stuff you need a person or a team that can do both software and hardware, and can make the appropriate decisions before the hardware is laid out.  Otherwise the hardware is just a guess, and the software designer starts out in a bind.

Comment: Since this question has been closed -- try http://reddit.com/r/ece.  Open-ended, opinion-based questions **are** encouraged there, and that's exactly what this is.

Answer (score 1):

So many ways to skin this cat. How many different samples does it need? How many seconds total of recording time? How large of a speaker are you planning to drive?

The tasks to be done include:

1. Program the sound samples into memory in the factory (or your garage)
2. Monitor the buttons to decide which sample to play
3. Retrieve sound samples from memory
4. Convert digital samples to an analog wave form
5. Amplify the analog wave form to a level strong enough to drive a speaker
6. Lather, rinse, repeat

There are, of course, other considerations to worry about, such as turning off the amplifier when not actively playing sound to prolong battery life, etc.

There is a whole range of solutions that can perform these steps; from doing it all in discrete hardware and software, to doing it all in one chip. The biggest determining factors are going to be how much engineering time and money you want to invest up front and how capable your hardware/firmware designer is.

It's very possible that the solution you pick for proof-of-concept (quick, for more money per piece) is not the same solution that you will want to go to production with (slower, but cheaper per piece).

At the risk of turning this into a shopping question...

- Maybe take a look at the [ISD ChipCorder](https://www.nuvoton.com/products/voice-ics/isd-chipcorder-family/) parts?
- Maybe try a Google search for "MP3 sound module"?
- For a proof of concept demo, maybe something like a [prototype playback board](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/14006)?

Comment: Thank you for this break down @spuck. It has occured to me as you mentioned in your post that the proof of concept solution can be different from the solution going into production. I guess my initial mistake was that I wanted to 'get it right' the first time. But from your comment and others here, I think I will favour getting the POC done and then depending on how that is accepted, look into going into production. Thank you also for the 'shopping list'. I will google these now

Comment: to answer your question specifically, I expect to have in total, about 2 minutes recording sound which is a combination of words and music. My hardware/firmware designer was sourced from a freelance site. I will prefer to have it all in one chip

Comment: If you want to have it all in one chip, the ISD ChipCorder parts are well-established. I used one in a project ~20 years ago. Now that the line is owned by Nuvoton I'm not sure how responsive or interested to support they would be to a "hobby" level project, but the parts are not difficult to use. Another approach I would consider might be a Cypress PSoC4 + SPI Flash memory + LM386 speaker driver.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will look into your recommendations.